Problema con redirigir a un formulario o menu segun el usuario y contraseña en google app script
// verifica la repuesta en inicio de session:
function verificarRespuesta(response) {
    const mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje');
      if (response.rol === 'Agentes') {
        google.script.run.mostrarFormularioAgentes();
      } else if (response.rol === 'Administrador') {
        google.script.run.mostrarFormularioAdministrador();
    } else {
      mensaje.textContent = response.message;
    }
  }

// mostrar formulario en codigo.gs:
// Funciones para abrir los formularios específicos
    function mostrarFormularioAgentes() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('FormsPagos').setTitle('Formulario de 
    Agentes');
   }

   function mostrarFormularioAdministrador() {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AdminMenu').setTitle('Menu de 
     Administrador');
   } 

despues de darle username y contraseña validadas no despliega el formulario ni el Menu.
soliciato su ayuda para poder resolver este tema que ya tengo tratando de resolver y no he podido. Muchas Gracias.

Hola, necesitas crear un [mre] para poder ver el problema. Incluye HTML necesario, y reproduce el problema que tienes en cuestión, además, mira la consola a ver si tienes algún error que no hayas visto.
